Taylor series of incomplete elliptic integral of first kind
Say I have an incomplete elliptic integral of first kind of the form
$$F(\varphi(z), k(z))=\int_0^{\varphi(z)} \frac{d \theta}{\sqrt{1-k(z)^2 \sin ^2 \theta}}$$
where each arguments are function of some variable $z$.
How do I taylor series $F$ in small z?
Thanks!

Each of the derivatives $$\frac{\partial^{a+b}}{\partial^a \varphi ,\partial^b k},F(\varphi,k)$$can be computed, but it will be complicated to write them in a single formula.

Where can I find the formula for the derivatives?
